# strongSwan 5, IKEv2 and L2TP server over IPSEC

Tags: networking, server, vpn, ipsec

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.zeitgeist.se/2013/11/22/strongswan-howto-create-your-own-vpn/) and managed to configure IKEv2 with strongSwan on my Ubuntu server. However I am not able to configure L2TP and IKEv2 simultaneously on it.
Previously, [L2TP/IPSEC was running with SoftEther](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-multi-protocol-vpn-server-using-softether#step-9-setup-l2tpipsec) . 
I have disabled L2TP on SoftEther and tried different configurations with IKEv2 and L2TP/IPSEC running on my server, but no luck.

Please, advice.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone has the same difficulty and reach this forum. I have managed to have Both L2TP/IPsec and IKEv2 with the SoftEther and Strongswan. 
In a few words, the L2TP is managed by SoftEther ( L2TP is also good with xl2tp or accel-pp ) and the IKEv2 + L2TP/IPsec is handled by StrongsWan